# Android: Edittext acting as search engine

Tags: android, android-edittext, search-engine

Is there a way that my Edittext in my application act as a search engine like google or yahoo? Is there any tutorial that can help me?

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to suggestions drop down in google?

Comment: Not only the dropdown... but I want the actual search results from google, yahoo

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html), for your purpose

refer this link also [Creating a Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve ?, but you can directly gettext from edittext and search that text using google api.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow  [this tutorial](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/)
Here if you search name automatically the matchings are highlight as like **Google**