# searchview in android to search in textview

Tags: android, searchview

Is it possible to implement a searchview widget to search from textview. My textview looks like this

### TextView  TextView    TextView

and I inflate these 3 textviews using layout inflater to show multiple values from a fragment.

**Fragment Class**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set the layout and inflater

    //perform some operations for button click
    return view;
}
```

**Activity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //do some operations with overflow menu
}

public  ArrayList<Asset> getData() {
    //perform operations so that data can be sorted to an array and then passed to textviews
}
```

I am confused as to where to include the searchview widget and how to make the textview searchable..

Answer (score 0):

you can include the search view widget in on-create method and you can follows these links to get your code :) 
please visist this : [How to set edittext to show search button or enter button on keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529485/how-to-set-edittext-to-show-search-button-or-enter-button-on-keyboard)
and also visist this : [Android: Edittext acting as search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407247/android-edittext-acting-as-search-engine)
i hope this will help you to find your answer thanks...:)

Comment: Thanks for the useful links, I still have a question on how to configure the search action to only search for values in my array/textview alone! I saw examples of including the search in the action bar, but I want it to be present only in one layout where I am searching for the textview results

Comment: you can apply filter in your adapter these above links show how to filter adapter on specific text..thanks